# How to find where the complex function $f(z)=|z| \bar z$ is differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, holomorphic-functions

I have tried using Cauchy-Riemann and I dont think it is differentiable anywhere but my solution book says it is on $0$ can someone explain to me why? Thanks for the time.

My calculations so far:

$f(x+iy)=x*\sqrt{x^2+y^2} -i(y*\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$

$u(x,y) = x*\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$v(x,y) = -y*\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{2x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{-xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{-2y^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

This means that $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}$ can never happen and therefore the function is not differentiable in any point rigth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(z) = |z|\overline{z}$ and so |${f(z)-f(0) \over z-0}| = |z|$, from which
it follows that $f'(0) = 0$.

However, to be analytic at $z=0$, the derivative needs to exist in a neighbourhood
of $z=0$, which it doesn't in this case.

**Aside**:
$|u(x,y)| = |x| \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = x^2 + y^2$. Hence
$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |{ u(x,y) - u(0,0) \over \sqrt{x^2+y^2} } | = 0$.
Similarly for $v$.

It would be better to write
${\partial u(x,y) \over \partial x} = \begin{cases} {2 x^2 + y^2 \over \sqrt{x^2+y^2} }, & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0, & (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$, etc, etc.

Comment: Sorry but i can`t understand how that helps me solve the problem could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: The above shows that $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$ which is what the your book says.

Comment: but my function is different from |z|^2 or is there any way to relate the both?

Comment: @Pedro: Sorry, I had a typo., the result is the same. Whenever you have $|f(z)| \le K |z|^\alpha$, with $\alpha >1$, the function $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$ and $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: I didnt use this method but using the Cauchy Riemann theorem i didnt get this answer. Do you think you can have a look to the original post i inputed  my calculations. Sorry for the delay took me some time to learn to edit the post

Comment: @Pedro: Well, your calculations are correct for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, but you need to be a little careful with formulae that are not defined at particular points, If you work through the details, both $u,v$ are differentiable at $(x,y) = (0,0) $ with derivative zero, so the Cauchy Riemann equations hold at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Comment: I think i understood as the partial derivatives are not defined for (0,0) using Cauchy Riemann we proved that all the values except (0,0) are not solutions for the problem we then need to see if (0,0) can be the answer.

Comment: @Pedro: No, the partial derivatives **are** defined, just not by the formula. If you compute the partials at $(0,0)$ you will find that they are zero. See my edit above.

Comment: I get it now thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x+iy)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x-iy)\\
u(x,y)=x\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
v(x,y)=-y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Now, check the CR equations, **and beware of the fact that the formulas you get for $u_x,u_y,v_x, v_y$ have a $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in the denominator, thus they don't work at $z=0$.** At $z_0$ you can calculate the partial derivatives with the definition, or you can check directly that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Using this method i got du/dx=(2x^2+y^2)/(x^2+y^2)^(1/2)

Comment: Sorry new to this i will put the partial derivatives in the original question

Comment: @Pedro And what is this when $x=y=0$? ;)

Comment: It is 0/0 so the partial derivatives are not defined for this point but that means that the function is not differentiable on 0 rigth?

Comment: @Pedro $0/0$ always means "more computations are needed"..It doesn't necessarily mean that the function is not differentiable.... You can calculate them at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ by using the limit definition....